# How can I query the source db of a webpage using Yii backend?

Tags: mysql, yii, sql-injection

I'm not sure if this is illegal, but I figured there's no harm in asking. The site is not actively maintained. I have tried contacting the website's owners and haven't had any response.

The website has an api to provide data to the public in JSON at `www.website.com/api/Query`. I periodically harvest data using the api (it shows the previous weeks worth of data). Recently, I received an error message while loading the site that pretty much showed the query used to load the data.

Something like this:

```
{"code":101,
 "status":"failure",
 "message":"CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: 
      SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2013 Lost connection to MySQL server /
      during query. The SQL statement executed was:
            SELECT * FROM table 
            WHERE created_date >= DATE_SUB(
                                 (select MAX(created_date) 
                                  from table), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)"
}
 CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: 
      SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away./
      The SQL statement executed was: 
            SELECT `id`
            FROM `YiiSession`
            WHERE id=:id
```

The issue resolved itself, but got me wondering if I could access historic data from the website. While I have basic understanding of how websites work in general, I have no idea how to approach this problem. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do not attempt to access data in an unauthorized manner. That's a criminal violation of the [Computer Fraud and Abuse Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_Fraud_and_Abuse_Act). You can do serious prison time for that. Even if the website owners don't respond, that doesn't give you the right to collect any data you want from their website. That's equivalent to *looting*.

Comment: I'm not from the US and the CFAA doesn't apply, but we've probably got similar laws in place; which was why I wasn't sure if it was illegal (seeing as I'm trying to access data which was openly available in the past). But I do get what you mean. Thanks for the response.